# Generate Datetime in the future without UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Lets say today is the `08.20.2014`.

I want to get the date from "today" additional 30 years (`08.20.2044`) with PHP and insert it into my mysql Database with it´s `Datetime` field.

How do I correctly generate the YYYY.MM.DD H:i:s without using the UNIX timestamp?

If i use

`mktime()` -> I get a UNIX timestamp (Limited, has a maxyear 2038, so nonsense)

`time()` -> I get a UNIX timestamp

`date()` -> I need a UNIX timestamp

`strtotime()` -> Im converting from/to UNIX timestamp

Am I completly missing a point?

What is the sense of using `DATETIME` if I´m using the UNIX timestamp in my code which is limited (I know that DATETIME is also limited to the year 9999)?

Comment: so what the problem for next 30 years if year datetime supports year to 9999

Comment: The unix timestamp is limited that's okay, but you still have a lot of time.
The datetime is huma readable and that's quite important if you use a database and sometimes you check it yourself.

Comment: Sidenote: This works too: date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 year'));

Comment: @Gerifield But not with +30 years...

Comment: Check gmdate() for Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)

Comment: @user1986811 that was an example only. Change the +1 to +30. :)

Comment: @Gerifield Doenst work, that´s the problem, try it yourself.

Comment: @user1986811 interesting. Okay, then use the datetime class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use unix timestamps in your code, use DateTime class.

```
$time = new DateTime();
$time->add(new DateInterval('P30Y'));

echo $time->format('Y-m-d');
```

it prints 2044-08-20

Comment: I´ll try that for my problem, seems legit. Saw this somewhere before, too.